# Get string from array via property lookup, but insert a variable

Tags: php, arrays, lookup, string-interpolation

I want to use property look-up on an associative array of strings, but there's a catch - I need to be able to use a variable in the string. I came up with two solutions, but both seem hacky in PHP.

```
$foo = [
  'someProp' => 'Some value here: $$value$$.'
];
$myProp = 'someProp';
$value = 'some value';
$myString = $foo[$myProp];
$myString = str_replace('$$value$$', $value, $myString);
echo $myString;
```

In JavaScript, I would probably use functions instead of strings and return the string including the variable. I've heard that this is bad practice in PHP.

```
$foo = array(
  'someProp' => function($value) {
    return "Some value here: {$value}.";
  }
);
$myProp = 'someProp';
$value = 'some value';
$myString = $foo[$myProp]($value);
echo $myString;
```

To be sure this is not an X/Y problem, I will say that my goal is to abstract my error messages to one location in my code (the array mentioned here) and form what might be considered an error api for use throughout the application. For example:

```
try {
  something(); //throws "MyException('someProp', 'someValue');
}
catch (MyException $e) {
  $someClass->addError($e->getType(), $e->getValue());
  //this function will get the string based on $type and add $value to it, then add the message to an array
}
```

**Are either of these two approaches the way to go?** The answer I'm looking for would include a more optimum solution if there is one and mature thoughts on my two proposed solutions.

Comment: Why do you treating replacing strings as a hack in PHP. Or else - what is not a hack then? Also - may be you want just to do proper formatting? Then no need to store format per each message, only messages - and format them inside display methods by formatter template

Comment: @AlmaDo I considered it "hacky" because I'm essentially creating my own string interpolation or concatenation system. The array of functions seems more natural, but is also a memory issue (I think). I don't quite see how I would implement your suggestion. If you care to expand on it, it might make a good answer.

Comment: I personally really don't get the problem with using closures here? Don't see why that should be bad practice (just not performant maybe…).

Comment: @bwoebi Performant, as in this? http://boulter.com/blog/2004/08/19/performant-is-not-a-word/ If so, your linguistic skills rock - awesome word. Also, performance is important in this case. I need to squeeze out every little bit.

Comment: @m59 Wah, I just take that word over from German. There's no reason why this adjective shouldn't exist (Dictionaries should just list it… it's their fault!). By the way, if performance is very important I'd just assign the bounty to @Rezigned. (`sprintf()` call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, is there only a single variable per message string or it could be many variables?

If there's only single variable, instead of role out your old string interpolation, you could use `sprinf` for this. This is more flexible in my opinion since it allows you to do many formatting types e.g. int, decimal etc

```
$foo = [
   'someProp' => 'Some value here: %s.'
];
$myString = sprintf($myString, $value);
```